# PHP MYSQL : way to list table in ascending order

Tags: php, mysql

we use " SHOW TABLES FROM " to list tables from database but there is no way to list table in order (ORDER BY dont work with tables)
is ther any other way to arrange it ??
can we do this with php :if yes please give me hint to do it
thank you

Answer (score 5):

You can use INFORMATION_SCHEMA:

```
SELECT table_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
  WHERE table_schema = 'db_name'
  ORDER BY table_name ASC
```

Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/tables-table.html

Comment: BUT the order i am getting is like this :

Comment: class_1
 class_10
 class_11
 class_12
 class_2
 class_3
 class_4
 class_5
 class_6
 class_7
 class_8
 class_9
which is not in asc order

Comment: That is ascending order, alphabetically. If you want to order based on the numbers appended to the end of the tables, you would need to split the table names into substrings, and order based on those substrings.

Answer (score 0):

Another option that doesn't rely on INFORMATION_SCHEMA:

Set up an array to store table options:

```
$tableArr = array();
```

Get the tables from the desired database:

```
$tableQuery = mysql_query("SHOW TABLES FROM databasse");
```

Add each table to your array:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($tableQuery)) {
  $tableArr[] = $row[0];
}
```

Now sort the array using asort (alphabetical) or arsort (reverse alphabetical):

```
asort($tableArr);
```

Now you can list the tables in alphabetical order by simply looping through the array:

```
foreach($tableArr as $table) {
  echo "<li>$table</li>";
}
```