# With mysql show tables; can I sort by table name while ignoring case?

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to sort the list of tables returned by mysql's 'show tables' command?

```
mysql> show tables;
```

I'd like to sort alphabetically by the table name.

EDIT:

As pointed out by one of the answers, they are already in alphabetical order. However, A != a. Is there a way to ignore case in the sort?

Comment: Duplicate: [PHP MYSQL : way to list table in ascending order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6076886/php-mysql-way-to-list-table-in-ascending-order)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Query information_schema and replace `database_name` with the name of the database you want to return the tables from

```
SELECT table_name, engine
FROM information_schema.tables    
WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE' AND table_schema='database_name'  
ORDER BY table_name ASC;
```

Answer (score 5):

They are already in alphabetical order!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONCAT(`table_name`, '') 
FROM information_schema.tables    
order by 1 asc
```

All you need, just transform the `table_name` to regular varchar type. And then order it as usual string.

Comment: Why do we need this? What type is `TABLE_NAME`, numeric?

Comment: Regards this [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-sensitivity.html) by default case insensitive works only with latin1 and latin1_swedish_ci collations. But the `table_name` is utf8_general_ci collation. Probably it is a case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one and replace database name accordingly.

> SELECT table_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.tables WHERE table_schema =
>   'database_name' ORDER BY table_name ASC;